# Why doesn't this for loop work when I simple change two expression's order

Tags: javascript, syntax

For the following fibonacci function, it works as expected:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  var nums = []
  var a = b = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    [a, b] = [b, a + b]
    nums.push(a)
  }
  return nums
}

console.log(fibonacci(5));
// outputs: [1,2,3,5,8]
```

but after I changed two statements' order, it doesn't work:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  var nums = []
  var a = b = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    nums.push(a)
    [a, b] = [b, a + b]
  }
  return nums
}

console.log(fibonacci(5));
// outputs: [1,1,1,1,1]
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You need semicolons.

Comment: @4castle This really works, but what's happening when the semicolons is missing?

Comment: javascript tries it's best to guess where you meant to put semicolons - it will get it wrong - with new syntax (like your `[a, b] = [b, a + b]` ) it probably gets it wrong more often than not ... moral of the story ... **always use semicolons**

Comment: @JaromandaX I see, thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually, it's not guessing - it just inserts them when needed, but not when the expression is valid without them.

Comment: poor terminology on my part - of course javascript does not guess :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you left out the semicolon at the end of the line

```
nums.push(a)
```

So it's merging the two lines into:

```
nums.push(a)[a, b] = [b, a + b]
```

This doesn't reassign the `a` and `b` variables, it's indexing an array.

You should really get out of the bad habit of omitting semicolons. Javascript allows it, but as you see in this example it doesn't always infer the statement breaks where you assume they would be.

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  var nums = [];
  var a = b = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    nums.push(a);
    [a, b] = [b, a + b];
  }
  return nums;
}

console.log(fibonacci(5));
// outputs: [1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Semi–colon insertion follows set rules, so really it's the OP that didn't correctly infer where semi–colons would (and would not) be inserted and the consequence. ;-)